# Snowflake INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS not being populated

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm running these queries with the ACCOUNTADMIN role - as this is a stated requirement here [TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS View](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/table_storage_metrics.html#table-storage-metrics-view).

If I run this query it returns records as expected:

```
select *
from snowflake.account_usage.table_storage_metrics
where TABLE_CATALOG = 'OPENBANKING'
limit 10;
```

However, if I try and query the table in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA in the database then the query runs but returns no data. I get the same result in every database I have tried.

```
select *
from "OPENBANKING"."INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS";
```

Does anyone know why I can't see the data in the xxx.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS views - or why there is no data in these views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only see records in the Information_Schema for those objects your current role has access privileges to, see here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema.html#general-usage-notes

Maybe accidentally your role on the worksheet-level is not set to ACCOUNTADMIN and you have to run a `USE ROLE ACCOUNTADMIN;` in front.

Comment: Cheers. I was logged in as ACCOUNTADMIN but on the worksheet I was using SYSADMIN - changing that to ACCOUNTADMIN resolved the issue